# jquery ui sortable list send updated order of of elements with ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I need order of all the elements like `item1=1&item2=2&item3=3` as soon as an element is sorted. here is the `js` fiddle for that code. could not paste as link due to indentation error.

**Fiddle**: [jsfiddle.net/8s8t99r7/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/8s8t99r7/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var order = [],
    counter = 1;

$('.sortable').sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    cursor: "move",
    update: function(event, ui) {
        order = [];
        counter = 1;
        $('.sortable div').each(function() {
            order.push($(this).attr('id') + "=" + counter++);
        });
        alert(order.join('&'));
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/8s8t99r7/4/